# How to determine if mouse is over axes using MATLAB GUIDE

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, axes

I know this question has been asked before, but I can't find any good answers. I keep stumbling upon `WindowButtonMotionFcn`, but I don't really understand how to use it. In my program I want to be able to click and store coordinates ONLY when the user is above a certain axes, so that the normal mouse appears for the rest of the GUI and they can play with other buttons. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not using `WindowButtonMotionFcn` and instead use the `ButtonDownFcn` of your axes object. This way MATLAB takes care of your hit detection for you.

For example:

```
function testcode()
h.myfig = figure;
h.myaxes = axes( ...
    'Parent', h.myfig, ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [0.5 0.1 0.4 0.8], ...
    'ButtonDownFcn', @myclick ...
    );
end

function myclick(~, eventdata)
fprintf('X: %f Y: %f Z: %f\n', eventdata.IntersectionPoint);
% Insert data capture & storage here
end
```

Prints your coordinate every time you click inside the axes but does nothing when you click anywhere else.

EDIT:

Since this is a GUIDE GUI the easiest approach is to utilize [`getappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) to pass data around the GUI. To start, you need to modify your `GUI_OpeningFcn` to something like the following:

```
function testgui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

% Choose default command line output for testgui
handles.output = hObject;

% Initialize axes click behavior and data storage
set(handles.axes1, 'ButtonDownFcn', {@clickdisplay, handles}); % Set the axes click handling to the clickdisplay function and pass the handles
mydata.clickcoordinates = []; % Initialize data array
setappdata(handles.figure1, 'mydata', mydata); % Save data array to main figure

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

And then add a click handling function elsewhere in your GUI:

```
function clickdisplay(~, eventdata, handles)
mydata = getappdata(handles.figure1, 'mydata'); % Pull data from main figure
mydata.clickcoordinates = vertcat(mydata.clickcoordinates, eventdata.IntersectionPoint); % Add coordinates onto the end of existing array
setappdata(handles.figure1, 'mydata', mydata); % Save data back to main figure
```

You can then pull the array into any other callback using the same `getappdata` call.

Comment: Thanks for the help, anyway you could explain that code a bit? I'm kind of lost. Also, In my GUI I have a function that gets coordinates from clicks: Thanks for the help, anyway you could explain that code a bit? I'm kind of lost. Also, In my GUI I have a function that gets coordinates from clicks: `function clickerCall(handles)
[handles.markedFrames(handles.markedIndex).x,handles.markedFrames(handles.markedIndex).y] = getpts(handles.axes1)
handles.markedIndex = handles.markedIndex+1
disp([handles.markedFrames.x])
updateAxes(handles);` and it should ideally run only when over a axes, Thanks!

Comment: Also, any idea how to store data from .IntersectionPoint into an array? I tried something like x = eventData.IntersectionPoint(1) to no avail

Comment: So I tried this: `handles.output = hObject;
handles.axesPos = get(handles.axes1,'Position');
handles.myaxes = axes(... 
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Position', [handles.axesPos], ...
    'ButtonDownFcn', @myclick ...
    );
` in an effort to use this function in my GUI, but its unresponsive any idea? sorry about the ton of questions

Comment: Hey @excaza, one last question: any idea why this would work on a blank axes, but not on my axes that I'm displaying images on with `imagesc(movImg,'parent',handles.axes1);`? Could it be that I'm fundamentally changing the axes with this line? Otherwise thank you so much this really helped, I also didn't know you could pass in handles with `{ }` so thanks for that as well.

Comment: `imagesc` creates an image object inside of your axes, so when you click you are clicking on that object and the axes hit detection is not triggered. Image objects also have a `ButtonDownFcn` property that can be defined in the same manner as we've been doing to the axes.

Comment: Thanks! I think I just got it.